# How to convert amount to french letters and with dinars as currency in ODOO9?

Tags: odoo, rml

Can anyone explain to me how can i convert AMOUNT to FRENCH LETTERS with DINARS as currency.
In fact, i have tried, this:

```
from openerp.report import report_sxw
from openerp.tools import amount_to_text_en
from openerp.tools import amount_to_text
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime, date, time

class declaration_cnss(report_sxw.rml_parse):

    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        print ('----------------------test--------------------------')
        super(declaration_cnss, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context)
        self.localcontext.update({
         'get_employee_lines': self.get_employee_lines,
         'amount_to_text': amount_to_text,
         'amount_to_text_en': amount_to_text_en
         })
```

And in my function i have this:
    amount_in_word = amount_to_text(somme_brut, lang='fr', currency='dinars')
But i got a warning:

```
2016-01-04 16:02:08,445 14045 WARNING ODOO       
openerp.tools.amount_to_text_en: no translation function found for lang: 'fr'
```

And the amount is converted to ENGLISH LETTERS.
Can anyone help please.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `amount_to_text_fr`.

*Replace*:

```
from openerp.tools import amount_to_text
```

*With*:

```
from openerp.tools.amount_to_text import amount_to_text_fr
```

Then call it using:

```
amount_in_word = amount_to_text_fr(somme_brut, 'dinars')
```